# PyTorch2.10 Parameters don't change after setting `requires_grad=True`

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

PyTorch2 removed `Variable`, and I replaced it with `torch.tensor(..., requires_grad=True)`.

Because my neural network has multiple loss values, I wanted the network to automatically balance them, so I multiplied the second loss value by λ, but λ didn't change during the process.

The simplified testing programme is as follows (the dataset `"../../data/test.txt"` is a txt with 4 columns):

```py
from torch import nn
import torch
import itertools
import numpy as np

class xxnet:
    def __init__(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, z1: np.ndarray, z2: np.ndarray) -> None:
        device = torch.device("cuda:0")
        self.net1 = self.construct_net()
        self.net2 = self.construct_net()
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
            itertools.chain(self.net1.parameters(), self.net2.parameters()),
            lr=0.01
        )
        self.x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True).reshape((x.shape[0], 1)).to(device)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True).reshape((x.shape[0], 1)).to(device)
        self.z1 = torch.tensor(z1, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True).reshape((x.shape[0], 1)).to(device)
        self.z2 = torch.tensor(z2, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True).reshape((x.shape[0], 1)).to(device)
        self.lambda_1 = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True).to(device)
        self.mse = nn.MSELoss().cuda("cuda:0")
        
    def construct_net(self):
        net = nn.Sequential()
        net.add_module('Linear_layer_1', nn.Linear(2, 20))
        net.add_module('Tanh_layer_1', nn.Tanh())
        net.add_module('Linear_layer_2', nn.Linear(20, 20))
        net.add_module('Tanh_layer_2', nn.Tanh())
        net.add_module('Linear_layer_3', nn.Linear(20, 1))
        net = net.cuda("cuda:0")
        return net
    
    def closure(self):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        f1 = self.net1(torch.hstack((self.x, self.y)))
        f2 = self.net2(torch.hstack((self.x, self.y)))
        z1 = gradients(f1, self.x)[0]
        z2 = gradients(f2, self.y)[0]
        
        loss_1 = self.mse(z1, self.z1)
        l2 = self.mse(z2, self.z2) * self.lambda_1
        loss_2 = gradients(l2, self.lambda_1)[0]
        self.ls = loss_1 + loss_2

        self.ls.backward()
        print(self.lambda_1)
        
        return self.ls
    
    def train(self):
        self.net1.train()
        # self.net2.train()
        self.optimizer.step(self.closure)

def gradients(outputs, inputs):
    return torch.autograd.grad(outputs, inputs, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(outputs), allow_unused=True, create_graph=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("../../data/test.txt", 'r') as f:
        data = np.loadtxt(f)
    X = data[:, 0]
    Y = data[:, 1]
    Z1 = data[:, 2]
    Z2 = data[:, 3]
    
    model = xxnet(X, Y, Z1, Z2)
    for i in range(10):
        model.train()
```

The main problem probably comes from this part:

```py
    def closure(self):
        ...
        z1 = gradients(f1, self.x)[0]
        z2 = gradients(f2, self.y)[0]
        
        loss_1 = self.mse(z1, self.z1)
        l2 = self.mse(z2, self.z2) * self.lambda_1
        loss_2 = gradients(l2, self.lambda_1)[0]
        self.ls = loss_1 + loss_2
        ...
```

where `self.lambda_1` is the parameter λ, initialized in the `__init__` function:

```py
    def __init__(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, z1: np.ndarray, z2: np.ndarray) -> None:
        ......
        self.lambda_1 = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True).to(device)
        ......
```

When outputting this parameter in `closure`, I found `self.lambda_1` didn't change.

```
tensor(1., device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>)
tensor(1., device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>)
tensor(1., device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>)
tensor(1., device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>)
...
tensor(1., device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>)
```

Comment: It seems that I need another single layer to control `self.lambda_1`, but I'm not sure whether there're other approaches.

Comment: As you don't provide an [MCVE], I can only guess. To me it seems that `self.lambda_1` does not change, because you didn't register it as a parameter to the optimizer.

Comment: I knew it, it's `torch.nn.Parameter()` , and this is a Multi-Task optimization.